Powershell help for Python uninstall
Looking to uninstall Python 3.12.3. using cmd.exe via intune. When I run the command via command it works as intended how ever when I use intune to push the command the CMD window appears and nothing happens.
This is the command that I have been using.
cmd.exe "C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Package Cache{5ee4d2b6-a5dc-4321-b6bd-3ebc98120a51}\python-3.12.3-amd64.exe" /uninstall /quiet
Not sure where I am going wrong or causing it to fail and looking for some help. I've also tried pushing this through powershell using
powershell.exe cmd /c "C:\Users%usernaame%\AppData\Local\Package Cache{5ee4d2b6-a5dc-4321-b6bd-3ebc98120a51}\python-3.12.3-amd64.exe"  /uninstall"

Double quotes is a typo. Kindly ignore. I've tried running it via powershell and the output is
"At line:1 char:114

... 4d2b6-a5dc-4321-b6bd-3ebc98120a51}\python-3.12.3-amd64.exe" /uninstal ...

                                                             ~



You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
At line:1 char:114


... d2b6-a5dc-4321-b6bd-3ebc98120a51}\python-3.12.3-amd64.exe" /uninstall

                                                            ~~~~~~~~~



Unexpected token 'uninstall' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression"

I had to split the return in two due to character limitations on stackoverflow field box.

I don't have Intune, but you can try this PowerShell code:
Edited needed according the path in your PC. {5ee4d2b6-a5dc-4321-b6bd-3ebc98120a51}
Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd.exe /c `"$Env:LOCALAPPDATA\Package Cache\{5ee4d2b6-a5dc-4321-b6bd-3ebc98120a51}\python-3.12.3-amd64.exe`" /Uninstall"

or autofind the file:
$PYExe = (GCI "$Env:LOCALAPPDATA\Package Cache\" -r | ? Name -Match 'python*').FullName
Iex -C "cmd.exe /c `"$PYExe`" /Uninstall"

